# How to fetch slack messages without using channel:history and group:history ouath?

Tags: python, slack

I built a slack bot at work that helps in DevOps automations and on demand tasks.
Some of the bot functionality was broken such as retrieving messages from slack channel because now my organization doesn't allow developers to use `channel:history` and `group:history` ouath in production!

Any idea how I can fetch data without using the mentioned permissions, or any other alternatives to the [classic retrieving data from slack](https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving#permissions)?